# why the `selfdestruct` not work in hardhat test?

Tags: hardhat, selfdestruct

Question edited:

It's pointed out in the comment that, I was wrong that `selfdestruct` can't be used to send token, only ether, but the problem still exists that the `selfdestruct` can be called 3 times.

My question:

I'm doing some test using hardhat, see code below, the `attackerContract.attack()` is called 3 times? After the first call, the contract is supposed to be destroyed and the second call would fail, but it's not, why?

The code:

// AttackUnstoppable.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract AttackUnstoppable {
    address target;

    constructor(address _target) {
        target = _target;
    }

    function attack() public payable {
        address payable a = payable(address(target));
        selfdestruct(a);
    }
}
```

// hardhat test script

```js
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('[Challenge] Unstoppable', function () {
    let deployer, attacker, someUser;

    // Pool has 1M * 10**18 tokens
    const TOKENS_IN_POOL = ethers.utils.parseEther('1000000');
    const INITIAL_ATTACKER_TOKEN_BALANCE = ethers.utils.parseEther('100');

    before(async function () {
        /** SETUP SCENARIO - NO NEED TO CHANGE ANYTHING HERE */

        [deployer, attacker, someUser] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const DamnValuableTokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('DamnValuableToken', deployer);
        const UnstoppableLenderFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('UnstoppableLender', deployer);

        this.token = await DamnValuableTokenFactory.deploy();
        this.pool = await UnstoppableLenderFactory.deploy(this.token.address);

        await this.token.approve(this.pool.address, TOKENS_IN_POOL);
        await this.pool.depositTokens(TOKENS_IN_POOL);

        await this.token.transfer(attacker.address, INITIAL_ATTACKER_TOKEN_BALANCE);

        expect(
            await this.token.balanceOf(this.pool.address)
        ).to.equal(TOKENS_IN_POOL);

        expect(
            await this.token.balanceOf(attacker.address)
        ).to.equal(INITIAL_ATTACKER_TOKEN_BALANCE);

        // Show it's possible for someUser to take out a flash loan
        const ReceiverContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('ReceiverUnstoppable', someUser);
        this.receiverContract = await ReceiverContractFactory.deploy(this.pool.address);
        await this.receiverContract.executeFlashLoan(10);
    });

    it('Exploit', async function () {
        const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther('2');

        // 1. deploy attacker contract
        const AttackerFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('AttackUnstoppable', deployer);
        const attackerContract = await AttackerFactory.deploy(this.pool.address);

        // 2. send some ether to attacker
        await this.token.connect(attacker).approve(
            attackerContract.address, amount)

        await this.token.connect(attacker).transfer(
            attackerContract.address, amount)

        console.log("balance before:", (await this.token.balanceOf(attackerContract.address)).toString())

        await attackerContract.attack();
        await attackerContract.attack();
        await attackerContract.attack();

        console.log("balance after:", (await this.token.balanceOf(attackerContract.address)).toString())
    });

    after(async function () {
        /** SUCCESS CONDITIONS */

        // It is no longer possible to execute flash loans
        await expect(
            this.receiverContract.executeFlashLoan(10)
        ).to.be.reverted;
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show the contract code. Also, `selfdestruct` doesn't send any tokens anywhere - only Ethers

Comment: Sorry for the missing information, post updated, and I shouldn't have said "token", it's "Ether".

Comment: You are not sending any Ether to the contract, only tokens. But unsure about the `selfdestruct` part - maybe some limitations with Truffle.

Comment: what version of hardhat are you using?

Comment: The version of hardhat is 2.12.0.